# asp.net mvc2 - controller for master page and code organization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-organization

I've just finished my first ASP.NET MVC (2) CMS. Next step is to build website that will show data from CMS's database. This is website design:

[http://img56.imageshack.us/img56/4676/portal.gif http://img56.imageshack.us/img56/4676/portal.gif](http://img56.imageshack.us/img56/4676/portal.gif)

**#1 (Red box)** - displays article categories. ViewModel:

```
public class CategoriesDisplay
    {
        public CategoriesDisplay() { }

        public int CategoryID { set; get; }
        public string CategoryTitle { set; get; }
    }
```

**#2 (Brown box)** - displays last x articles; skips those from green box #3. Viewmodel:

```
public class ArticleDisplay
    {
        public ArticleDisplay() { }

        public int CategoryID { set; get; }
        public string CategoryTitle { set; get; }

        public int ArticleID { set; get; }

        public string ArticleTitle { set; get; }
        public string URLArticleTitle { set; get; }
        public DateTime ArticleDate;

        public string ArticleContent { set; get; }

    }
```

**#3 (green box)** - Displays last x articles. Uses the same ViewModel as brown box #2

**#4 (blue box)** - Displays list of upcoming events. Uses `dataContext.Model.Event` as ViewModel

Boxes #1, #2 and #4 will repeat all over the site and they are part of Master Page. So, my question is: what is the best way to transfer this data from Model to Controller and finally to View pages?

1. Should I make a controller for
   master page and ViewModel class that will wrap all this classes together OR
2. Should I create partial Views for
   every of these boxes and make each
   of them inherit appropriate class
   (if it is even possible that it
   works this way?) OR
3. Should I put this repeated code in
   all controllers and all additional
   data transfer via ViewData, which
   would be probably the worse way :) OR
4. There is maybe a better and more
   simple way but I don't know/see it?

Thanks in advance,
Ile

**EDIT:**
If your answer is #1, then please explain how to make a controller for master page!


**EDIT 2:**
In this tutorial is described how to pass data to master page using abstract class: http://www.asp.net/LEARN/mvc/tutorial-13-cs.aspx
In "Listing 5 – Controllers\MoviesController.cs", data is retrieved directly from database using LINQ, not from repository. So, I wonder if this is just in this tutorial, or there is some trick here and repository can't/shouldn't be used?

Comment: Is it possible to make a strongly typed master page in MVC?

Comment: I would also like to know answer ti this question

Comment: the answer for passing data to Master Page is here: http://www.asp.net/LEARN/mvc/tutorial-13-cs.aspx

Comment: I would create Views, ViewModels and Actions for each section. Then call Html.RenderAction(...).

Comment: Now that I've read this solution from my comment above, I think this solved my problems. So, I should create an abstract Controller, put all repeated data inside it and make all other controllers inherit from it so that all data from that abstract class is available in all controllers that inherit from it.

Comment: @mxmissile nice solution!, post it as an answer : )

Comment: @mxmissile, I'm not pretty sure what you want to say. Could you please be more precise. I've just read these posts and now many things are much more clear to me: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/12/asp-net-mvc-tip-31-passing-data-to-master-pages-and-user-controls.aspx and http://www.asp.net/LEARN/mvc/tutorial-13-cs.aspx.
Is your solution anyhow connected with these two posts?

Comment: I edited my question again, it's about this abstract class

Comment: I added an answer below, with a little more info than what I posted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get data to my Master Page:

- I don't like using an abstract class to get data to the master page. I prefer composition over inheritance.
- I don't like to use the ViewData dictionary because it's not strongly typed.

I would create Views, ViewModels and Actions for each section. Then call `Html.RenderAction(...)` For example:

I would create `CategoriesDisplay.aspx` with only the html for the redbox.  I would pass that your `CategoriesDisplay` model. Then in my controller:

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult DisplayCategories()
    {
      var model = new CategoriesDisplay();
      ...
      return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then in my Master Page:

```
<% Html.RenderAction<CategoryController>(c => c.DisplayCategoreis()); %>
```

This will render the CategoriesDisplay view inline within the Master Page. Which in turn allows you have SOC (Seperation of Concerns), clean and manageable code.

Comment: I probably should add, the Html.RenderAction extension I used is part of the Asp.Net MVC futures assembly. http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742

Comment: I see... didn't know what was this Html.RenderAction so I was a bit sceptic. This definitely sounds like more interesting solution than the one with abstract class. I will try it in a day or two and see if it really all works to me :) Thanks maxmissile!

Comment: Is it possible to make one controller action and us it in different views? To be more precise, is it possible to define inside Html.RenderAction() wich Controller, which Action and which View to use?

Comment: Yes RenderAction can be called from any view and pointed to any Controller.

Answer (score 2):

I fought with this as well. Initially I did a lot of dumping of extra data into the ViewData, which ended up having to be casted back (made some extensions that eased this, but still not great).

I would go with your choice #1 and make a ViewModel that wraps all of the classes you would need.

Comment: I edit my question... I forgot to add that I have no idea how to make controller for master page (I'm asp.net newbie)